# Unable to convert age function to a float with Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to write a query to output the average earnings per hour spent dashing by day of week.

worker_table:-

| session_id | worker_id | session_start | session_end | total_pay | num_of_deliveries |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7712 | 9347 | 2020-08-31 03:32:43 | 2020-08-31 05:53:43 | 46.72 | 3 |
| 1560 | 5645 | 2020-07-26 01:48:40 | 2020-07-26 04:48:40 | 65.32 | 4 |

So far I am able to extract the day of week and age but I'm not too sure how to cast the age to numeric so I can proceed with my query. When I run the query below, the age would be "02:21:00" but I want it to be a float so I can divide total_pay with age. Thanks.

```
select extract(dow from session_start), age(session_end, session_start)
from worker_table
```

**Edit:** If For some reason the table is not showing correctly. Please view my table here: https://pastebin.com/g8GvyWWR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the number of seconds from an interval, you can use `extract epoch`. In your case, you could do something like this -

```sql
select extract(epoch from age(session_end, session_start)) as session_length_in_seconds
from worker_table
```

The full query might then look something like this -

```sql
select 
    extract(dow from session_start), 
    avg(total_pay / (extract(epoch from age(session_end, session_start)) / 3600.0)) as avg_earnings_per_hour
from worker_table 
group by 1
```